# Layer depth problem in XNA puzzle game

Tags: xna

I am working on puzzle game where tiles are needed to be dragged to their correct place, but at the time of dragging one of the textures goes behind the other texture. How can I bring the texture to the top?

```
       private void OnDraw(object sender, GameTimerEventArgs e)
       {
                         SharedGraphicsDeviceManager.Current.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

         // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        Color transp = Color.White;
     //   transp.A = 200;
        spriteBatch.Begin();       

                   spriteBatch.Draw(Texture.piece[1],Texture.piecerect[1],null, transp,0,Vector2.Zero,SpriteEffects.None,1);


        spriteBatch.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use deafult  `spriteBatch.Begin()`, then textures draw in order you call them. This mean you must simply draw dragging texture after background texture

```
                        spriteBatch.Begin();
                        spriteBatch.Draw(backgroundTexture, position,Color.White);
                        spriteBatch.Draw(draggingTexture, position,Color.White);
                        spriteBatch.End();
```

Another approach that i can suggest is to implement draw layers. One way to do that is to  create an array from 0 to 5 for example and let 0 be top layer. Then assign to each texture layer number. Change texture layer in `Update` as you want.  In `Draw` you then just simply iterate from 5 to 0 layer and draw coresponding to this layer textures.

Comment: it increased my code line's too much...because of puzzle tiles are randomly generated so its quite tricky to handle their sequence... but solved the problem so easily ..just becasue of your idea

Comment: `SpriteBatch` itself has depth support, so there's no need to implement this yourself.